# which is the best API to read large sized excel files in Java?

Tags: java, excel

what my application needs are

1) Read large sized excel files with .xls or .xlsx format

2) insert every column as a row in database with previous column as a parent of next

means if i am having 5 columns and 30,000 rows then i want to insert 1 column as parent,
  2nd column is child of 1st column, 3rd column is child of 2nd so on...i.e. tree structure

now can anyone suggest me best API to do this in java language.

after some googling i found there are lots of API's present but which is the best out of that

Reference [see](http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html)

Comment: I have the **exact** same problem. And so far, no solution. POI wants to load the entire XLSX in to memory. If you're just working with XLS files, POT-3.8b5 will load and process the file in seconds! I had a 209MB XLS files and my application processed the whole thing (500,000 rows across 8 tabs) and inserted in to MySQL in about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try POI, I am not sure if they read .xlsx, maybe they do in newest versions.

Comment: yes, I found newer version of POI have support for .xlsx (POI 3.6)

Answer (score 5):

I have used both [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) in the past and have stuck to JExcel because it is easier to use with better documentation. I also found that POI used more memory when writing data out to a spreadsheet.

I would recommend JExcel and I would be happy to help if you encounter any problems.

Comment: I am more familiar with POI, but I hear good things about jExcel, like better documentation and scalability.

Comment: is JExcel support .xlsx file format?

Comment: ok. as you suggested to use JExcel so, i gone through this documentation of Jexcel API and i found there is no support for .xlsx  http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

And you can't do an export to a .csv file?

This would maybe be a much faster solution then parsing the whole .xls/.xlsx file.
Another point is that you than only have to deal with one file type/format.

Comment: I don't believe that JExcel deals with .xlsx properly.  Not sure about POI.  I agree with your point - exporting .csv sounds better.

Comment: Not so handy if the point is some automation is needed where some non-technical business person just wants to dump an excel file in an upload box on a web interface of similar. Exporting to CSV is a manual step, or requires some VBA thing - also not usable if the system running it is not a windows box.

Answer (score -1):

Try POI - it will read the file (XLS, XLSX) but the database manipulations require other libraries and basic JDBC as well.

Comment: While POI can read both XLS and XLSX files, it is a memory hog in the latter case. SXSSFWorkBook loads the **entire** XSLX files in to memory. A 38MB XLSX file needs well more than -Xmx2048x!! [Redonculous](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=redonculous)!!