# Reading data from xlsx with Apache POI's SXSSFSheet

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to read data ( cell values ) from a certain xlsx file using apachi poi. 
The code below creates the `SXSSFWorkBook` instance successfully and assigns db.xlsx ( my dummy xlsx). I have tried changing sheet numbers and double checking it with the `getSheetNumber` method to make sure the workbook is correctly assigned.

Next I want to assign a specific sheet (index `0` with name `main`) to `SXSSFSheet` instance, but currently it returns `null`. (I have both tried `getSheetAt` and `getSheet` methods).

```
SXSSFRow DummyRow;
SXSSFCell DummyCell;

int RowCount;
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(blabla string adress);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
Workbook MainBook = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb,100);

int a = MainBook.getNumberOfSheets();

SXSSFSheet MainSheet = (SXSSFSheet) MainBook.getSheetAt(0); 
RowCount = MainSheet.getLastRowNum();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have tried `getSheetName` method and had a positive result. So the problem is with reaching rows in Worksheet. so, the last line `getLastRowNum()` is not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't. SXSSFWorkBook is write only, it doesn't support reading

For low memory reading of .xlsx files, you should look at the [XSSF and SAX EventModel documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)