# XLSX to CSV out of memory error

Tags: java, excel, csv, xlsx, xssf

I found plenty of solutions how to convert XLSX to CSV file using Java, all the solutions use: `XSSFWorkbook`. Problem I am facing is that probably the stream is having too much data. I just don't get why, the file is just 4mb.

CODE:

```
// For storing data into CSV files
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        System.out.println("Getting input stream.");
        // Get the workbook object for XLS file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        System.out.println(" - Done");
        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        Row row;

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        System.out.println(" - Reading xlsx rows.");
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            i++;

            row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ";");
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ";");
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ";");
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    data.append("" + ";");
                    break;

                default:
                    data.append(cell + ";");
                }

            }
            data.append('\n');
            int limit = 10000;
            if ((i % limit) == 0) {
                System.out.println(" - Writing " + limit + " data.");
                fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
                fos.flush();
                data = null;
                data = new StringBuffer();
                System.out.println(" - Data written.");
            }
        }

        fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

The error is pointing to line in switch statement where I am appending something to data (StringBuffer), but I am nulling it so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You are stuffing things in a `StringBuffer` which might not be that efficient. Why store it in memory anyway? Just create a single line, write that to file and move on (you probably want to use a `BufferedWriter`. Also why are you creating a String and converting it to a `byte[]` next that duplicates the memory footprint. Depending on the speed of your JVM and GC you get a lot of additional objects. One thing to try and start with is to lower your limit, and instead of constructing a new `StringBuffer` just empty it and reuse. Instead of a `StringBUffer` I suggest the use of a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Yeah, before I have used just setLength(0) but the issue was not there, it was during the fileInputStream.

Comment: Large objects can linger around so reusing might be better. The fact that it occurs while reading doesn't mean it is because of the reading. Your memory is filling up and the large `StringBuffer` would be my first to fix. Another note is that you are using `StringBuffer` but still are using String concat to add Strings. I suggest removing the `+ ";"` from your case statement and add a `data.append(';')` after the case statements. Saves creating additional String for concat.

Answer (score 0):

Now you may not be able to use SXSSFWorkbook (as it's write-only), but you may be able to convert your program to streaming-style using the [SAX-based API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api). Edit: Another thing you may want to try is to create the XSSFWorkbook from File instead of InputStream (I remember reading somewhere that the File-based code needs less memory).

(First try was:
Since you are reading data sequentially the [SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) class should be just the thing you need.)

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook is write only, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513981/reading-data-from-xlsx-with-apache-pois-sxssfsheet

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx format is just a zip with content xml and shared-strings xml. Hence 4 MB compressed, may well be very large uncompressed.

Using a zip file system you could load the shared strings into memory, and then read content xml sequentially, immediately outputting.

As two inner files are concerned, you might use java's zip file system. Tedious but not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

try this code this one is perfectly working for me i hope that also working for you.

```
package com.converting;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class XlsxtoCSV {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
             FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/blackpearl/Downloads/aa.xlsx"));
             XSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
             XSSFSheet  my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 

             Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
             FileWriter my_csv=new FileWriter("/home/blackpearl/Downloads/Newaa.csv");
             CSVWriter my_csv_output=new CSVWriter(my_csv); 
             while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                     Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                     int i=0;//String array
                     String[] csvdata = new String[20];
                     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                             while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                     Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                                     switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                             csvdata[i]= cell.getStringCellValue();                                              
                                             break;
                                     }
                                     i=i+1;
                             }
             my_csv_output.writeNext(csvdata);
             }
             System.out.println("file imported");
             my_csv_output.close(); //close the CSV file
             input_document.close(); //close xlsx file
     }
}
```