# how to use StreamingReader with asset files , getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/attribute/FileAttribute;

Tags: java, android

I am using [this library](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.monitorjbl/xlsx-streamer/2.1.0/jar) for fast reading xlsx file kept in asset folder android as it was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786506/8361923)

while running the app i am getting following error

```
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.djsde.splashactivity, PID: 31903
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/attribute/FileAttribute;
        at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.TempFileUtil.writeInputStreamToFile(TempFileUtil.java:11)
        at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:88)
        at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader$Builder.open(StreamingReader.java:251)
        at com.example.djsde.splashactivity.Puzzle.<init>(Puzzle.java:99)
        at com.example.djsde.splashactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6275)
        at ...
```

on clicking Puzzle.java:99 it takes me to following part of code

```
    InputStream myInput;
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(xlname);
                myInput = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
                Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder()
                        .rowCacheSize(100)    
                        .bufferSize(4096)    
                        .open(myInput); //this line 
...
```

my gradle app file i have altered following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "xlsx"
    }

    packagingOptions {
               exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
               exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
               exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
               exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
               exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude  'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {   


    implementation 'com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0'


    api group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'aalto-xml', version: '1.0.0'
}
```

adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And set `multiDexEnabled true` inside defaultConfig to turn multidexing on. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because you have not enabled multidexing. You need to add following dependency to your gradle.

`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

And set multiDexEnabled true inside defaultConfig to turn multidexing on.

Comment: problem still there

Comment: if it might help :                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.djsde.splashactivity-2/base.apk", zip file......