# Out of memory Error When reading a large excel file using apache POI. Any other alternative

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read a very large excel file using Apache POI.
But it is throwing a heap size out of memory error. There is no chance I can increase the heap size.Are there any other solutions for this.

Comment: Can you read the file piece wise, by breaking into smaller chunks? Or do you need the entire file in the memory at the same time?

Comment: For one operation i can read it in small chunks, For the other I have to load the complete file.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem related to Swing. Tag removed.

Comment: *"I want to read a very large excel file"* BTW - is it for read only? Is there any need to update that information and write the file?

Comment: @hina If you have to load the complete file, then you will need the entire file in memory. You cannot do without extra heap space

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson  With one excel file I have to just read the excel data and store it in the database. With the second excel file I have to read and Perform few operations and write it back to the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, [POI's streaming API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) might be the solution. It avoids loading the whole file into memory at the same time but is limited in its functionality.

[The answers to this question might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786219/apache-poi-streaming-sxssf-for-reading) as one of them suggests a [library that makes working with the streaming API easier](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader).

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the streaming api library. This helped me greatly!