# How to add a sheet to an existing large excel file(20MB) using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file of size 20MB. I want to add a new sheet to this file. I am using Apache POI for this. But when I load the workbook, I am getting heap memory exception at the below line:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)));
```

I have tried searching for alternative but everyone is suggesting to increase my heap memory, but I cannot do this in the server side. Please help me!

One more thing! Is it possible to create a new sheet in the existing excel file through opcpackage. If yes, how?

Below is the code for your reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("fileName.xls"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        System.out.println("Number of sheets: " + wb.getNumberOfSheets());
        pkg.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

at line:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Thankyou!

Comment: Did you try with SXSSF? Also does [using a File rather than an InputStream as per the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) help?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using it and still faced the exception:

Comment: Yes, I have tried using SXSSF and File instead of InputStream but still faced the same exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space .

Comment: Can anyone tell me is it possible to create a new sheet in an existing excel file using OPCPackage? If yes, how?

Comment: OPC is the low level packaging layer, which stores the XML files and links between them. You really need to move up a level to XSSF or SXSSF, manipulating the XML files and their relations + dependencies isn't much fun

Comment: Can you state with how much memory you actually run this? SXSSF should not use a lot of memory even with very large documents, so it might some other problem after all.

Comment: @centic: As far as I know SXSSF supports write only, it doesn't support reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513981/reading-data-from-xlsx-with-apache-pois-sxssfsheet. I have a .xls file which is 20MB. It has 11 sheets, and each sheet has 49152 records.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents is not too complicated you can use the [streaming-input](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) functionality and construct a new SXSSFWorkbook with that data in streaming-output fashion, thus not requiring to hold the complete workbook in memory.

There is also a more [elaborate example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) that shows how reading information can be done in streaming fashion.

Naturally this will be complicated if there is lots of styling/formatting applied in the source document.